# I am trying to open port 19132 on my Ubuntu server, but not working

Tags: networking, port-forwarding

I am trying to set up a server for my son to play `Pocketmine`.  This is a `PHP` server and it is running on port 19132.  I have opened this port on my router and if I run another server, like a Rails server, then everything is fine.  When I try to run `Pocketmine`, the port is never open.  I have the server running now.  Here is my `netstat` output.

[image: Netstat output]

You can see the server, it is the first line that is a `udp port`.  I see that it does not have a state of `LISTEN`.  Here is the output from my server.
[image: Server Output]

What could be the problem?  Why does the `udp` server not it a state of `LISTEN`?  Does it need to be in a state of `LISTEN`?  What else could be the problem to stop the port from being open?  What do I do to trouble shoot this?

Comment: I'm pretty sure that UDP never shows listening. Only established when there's an actual active connection. The nature of UDP is that is always listening.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

#### Idea #1 - UDP port forwarding?

Confirm that when you opened this port on your router that you specified either both TCP/UDP or UDP. The types of these ports matters, and can often be overlooked when opening ports on ones firewall/router.

#### Idea #2 - Port forward on pocketmine realms issue?

I came across this forum post which sounds like exactly the issue you're having. It even shows screenshots that this particular user used to open up the UDP port on his router and he was still not able to get it working.

- http://forums.pocketmine.net/index.php?threads/port-forward-on-pocketmine-realms-issue.14/

Answer (score 3):

The reason why you don't see `LISTEN` on the minecraft server port is due to the way the UDP protocol works.

A server that uses the TCP protocol "listens" for a connection so that when a client tries to connect, it will commence a session and transfer data using the TCP/IP protocol. If there is nothing "listening" on a certain port for TCP connections, the protocol itself can generate an error to say that it couldn't connect to a server that was listening on a port.

UDP connections don't have sessions, and as such they don't "listen" for connections. What actually happens is that a UDP packet is sent to that port, and if there is a server receiving packets on that port then the data will be processed. Otherwise if there is nothing receiving packets, then that packet disappears into the void, and no error will be generated on the protocol level.

The fact that you can see the port 19132 on the netstat means that in the UDP world, the server is "listening" for data on that port, which means that the port is actually open.